# What program to use to change settings on db servers?

Tags: mysql, replication

Having decided to set up a Master-Slave replication I found [this](http://cloudservers.rackspacecloud.com/index.php/MySQL_replication_-_Master/Slave) article, which seems exactly what I want.

So I fired up the MySQL Console in Navicat to give everything a try, and the commands do nothing. So it seems one of these is the problem:

- The MySQL Console is not the tool I want
- The MySQL Console on Navicat is imperfect
- I am doing it wrong

This is the first step in the article I linked:

> /sbin/ifconfig

Does nothing on the remote server connection (using the Console in Navicat) but works fine on the MySQL Console on the WAMP Server on my local machine.

---

UPDATE:

next day - clear head - realize what I was trying to do is probably not possible and not necessary. Web site is hosted on some rackspace servers in California, and I doubt they want me messing around with their server settings.

I was trying to set up separate databases so that the write-heavy backend did not interfere with reads in the front end. This morning I reworked the calls which were causing table locks & now the slow backend queries should not lock any table required by the front end.

So basically problem solved. This why I should only post on here in the morning, not after 8-10 hours coding.

Comment: What OS are you using? If you are on Ubuntu, just use `ifconfig` (probably as sudo)

Comment: @JIStone you know that the /sbin/ifconfig is a unix/linux command that manages internet configurations, right? It should _not_ work on a WAMP server, as that would be a windows machine.

Comment: @jcolebrand OK /sbin/ifconfig does nothing by \sbin\ifconfig does something. . . I know nothing about OS/Servers, but our tech support is somehow even more ignorant . . .

Comment: I rather meant that /sbin is not a directory on Windows.

Comment: I wonder, could you edit your question and post us a list of the steps, verbatim, of what you're doing? I wonder if you're not getting far enough "into" where you need to go.

Comment: @jcolebrand posted an update . . .

Comment: haha with the update. Sorry that you had to suffer all that to just solve your own problem. I love my morning shower, it's where I figure out all my worst problems from yesterday ;)

Comment: @JIStone : This question should help invite other MySQL DBA/Users to hopefully suggest additional tools they prefer. +1 for this question !!!

Answer (score 3):

As a MySQL DBA, may I be so bold as to suggest my favorite tool?

[**The mysql client program itself**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html)

[There are also a variety of startup options for the client program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html).

Examples:

```
-h hostname or host IP
-P port number
-u username
-p password
-e allows execution of a semicolon delimited list of SQL queries inside double quotes
--skip-column-names will suppress the column heading for output of SQL queries
```

You see all the options by doing this

```
mysql --help --verbose
```

You can see global variables and status in the mysql instance using **SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;** and **SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;** You can also see session variables and status in the db connection using **SHOW VARIABLES;** and **SHOW STATUS;**

Once you have successfully connected to the mysql instance, [you have a wide variety of session and server options that you can set for the current session or permamnently for all new sessions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html).